# CSS grid cell width in Firefox is greater than its content

Tags: css, firefox, css-grid

I have a div with height: 15vw; , i want to place 4 images into this div (every image size is 1920*1080 px), if i use below code, everything in chrome is OK, but in Firefox, each image size is 195*110 (it's OK) but each grid cell width is 1920px ! I want the width of each cell to be equal to the width of the image.

https://codepen.io/arsenal2323/pen/yLNPoXV

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background-color: green;
  height: 15vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: min-content;
  gap: 10px;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/412020/ss_f0297eacbfb4266f311a8cb4137e4ef8b7cdd00b.jpg?t=1582550242" alt="" class="image">
  <img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/412020/ss_bd875dbf865e70cda73a7cd6b132cadacfdb768b.jpg?t=1582550242" alt="" class="image">
  <img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/412020/ss_7ef17676a804b0d646c38583ba0f68f33b3f3d9e.jpg?t=1582550242" alt="" class="image">
  <img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/412020/ss_23815433fdd4a63064da79222fdefb569eeafaba.jpg?t=1582550242" alt="" class="image">
</div>
```

chrome:
[preview in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZBvS.png)

Firefox:
[preview in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slXcy.png)

Comment: in some browser like ie and firefox, the image container size equals to main image width, when you use the % for width. you can use px, em, rem for set the absolute size. (dont use % and use px).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the container tag display property to 'table' and adding display 'table-cell' property to img tag worked for me.[here](https://codepen.io/salman61s/pen/bGdYoPv)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    background-color: green;
  width:100%;
    height: 15vw;
    display: table;
}

.image {
  width:25%;
   display:table-cell;
  padding:10px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/412020/ss_f0297eacbfb4266f311a8cb4137e4ef8b7cdd00b.jpg?t=1582550242"
            alt="" class="image">
        <img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/412020/ss_bd875dbf865e70cda73a7cd6b132cadacfdb768b.jpg?t=1582550242"
            alt="" class="image">
        <img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/412020/ss_7ef17676a804b0d646c38583ba0f68f33b3f3d9e.jpg?t=1582550242"
            alt="" class="image">
        <img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/412020/ss_23815433fdd4a63064da79222fdefb569eeafaba.jpg?t=1582550242"
            alt="" class="image">
</div>
```

Comment: If i have "n" images ( 1 < n < 100) and want to arrange them in two rows (half of images in row 1 and another half in row 2), What should I do ??

Comment: add any no of images it will work but each rows appears 4 column of images